# Set of limit points on a topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology

I like to solve this problem.

"**Problem:** In any topological space, the set of limit points of a sequence is closed."

The proof is easy when we work with metric spaces, but how can I generalize this result? Is this result true in topological spaces that are not first-countable?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: A limit point of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a point $y$ such that for every neighbourhood $U$ of $y$ the set $\{ n\in\mathbb{N} : x_n \in U\}$ is infinite? Or is it such that $\{n\in\mathbb{N} : x_n \notin U\}$ must be finite? (Just checking definitions)

Comment: Yeah, if you want, let's denote this fact by $x_n \rightarrow x$

Comment: So the second? Not that it makes much of a difference. Let $L$ be the set of limit points, and suppose $z \in \overline{L}$. That means every neighbourhood (which can be assumed to be open) of $z$ ... and therefore $z\in L$. The proof does not use any topological properties of the space, only the definitions of the closure of a set (or a characterisation of the points in the closure) and the definition of a limit point of a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a set of limit points of a sequence, say ($x_n$) in a topological space $X$. Consider the set $X-A$.

Let $c \in {X-A}$. Hence, $c \notin A$.

$\implies \exists\ \ U$ open in X such that $A \cap U = \emptyset$ by definition of limit point.

$\implies U \subset {X-A}$

Therefore, as c is arbitrary, for every element in $X-A$, $ \exists$ $U_c$ open such that, $c \in {U_c}$ and ${U_c} \subset {X-A}$. That is X-A is open. Hence, A is closed.